# Connections not closed from Azure Functions to Azure Servicebus

Tags: azure

I have an Azure function that has a few service bus triggers on the azure service bus. One of them is using the beta feature IsSessionEnabled based on this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/529) but i'm not sure if this is related to the following problem.

On the development and test/acceptance environments it works fine, also with higher loads. On production the function is running out of the connection limit of 2k. Based on the "Diagnose and solve problems/TCP Connections" in the function app I found that there were around 1900 connections to the servicebus.
I'm currently running out of ideas what configurations etc. I can check to figure this out.

Comment: Since this appears to be focused on programming and software development, might this fit better in http://webapps.stackexchange.com or http://stackoverflow.com ?  Ref: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @K7AAY. I think you're right. I'll keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue.
I did make all the Http clients singleton as described in the best practices of Azure functions. I missed the QueueClient though which sends messages to the service bus. Now I have made that a singleton and it looks like it doesn't create a new connection every time.